# Merge two tables and insert/update respectively

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have two tables and I have to merge the records.

source:

```
ID  seq  name    designation   company
001   1  aaa     Developer      YYY
001   2  aaa     lead        yyy
002   1  mmm     consultant     bbb
003   1  ppp     developer      yyy
003   2  ppp     lead           yyy
003   3  ppp     manager        yyy
```

target:

```
ID  seq  name    designation   company
001   1  aaa     Developer      YYY
001   2  aaa     lead        yyy
002   1  mmm     consultant     bbb
003   1  ppp     developer      yyy
003   2  ppp     lead           yyy
003   3  ppp     manager        yyy
```

I want to write merge to insert/update records. My key columns are ID and seq both.they are composite primary keys.
generally it is an update record we get. For example, ID 001 has two records in source . if ID 001 gets another record with sequence 3 , then this record should go as an insert in target.

if my source now has 
source:

```
ID  seq  name    designation   company
001   1  aaa     Developer      YYY
001   2  aaa     lead           yyy
001   3  aaa     manager        yyy
002   1  mmm     consultant     bbb
003   1  ppp     developer      yyy
003   2  ppp     lead           yyy
003   3  ppp     manager        yyy
```

then target should be:
target:

```
ID  seq  name    designation   company
001   1  aaa     Developer      YYY
001   2  aaa     manager        yyy
001   3  aaa     manager        yyy
002   1  mmm     consultant     bbb
003   1  ppp     developer      yyy
003   2  ppp     lead           yyy
003   3  ppp     manager        yyy
```

I am trying with below merge and it is not working for me.

```
MERGE target t 
using source s 
on  s.ID=t.ID and s.seq=t.seq
when not matched
then 
Insert
(
ID,
seq,
name,
designation,
company
)
Values
(
s.ID,
s.seq,
s.name,
s.designation,
s.company
)
when matched
then 
update
set

name=s.name,
designation=s.designation,
company=s.company
;
```

Can you please let me know where am I going wrong?
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify `NOT MATCHED BY TARGET`

Just try the following Query:

```
MERGE TABLE1 AS TARGET
USING TABLE2 AS SOURCE 
ON  (SOURCE.ID = TARGET.ID AND SOURCE.seq = TARGET.seq)

WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET 
name=SOURCE.name,
designation=SOURCE.designation,
company=SOURCE.company

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
INSERT(ID,seq,name,designation,company)
VALUES(SOURCE.ID,SOURCE.seq,SOURCE.name,SOURCE.designation,SOURCE.company)

--If You want to delete rows found in TARGET and not found in SOURCE add the following line

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
DELETE
```